# Raw therapee lens/geometry correction Sony a6100

Tags: lens, raw, rawtherapee

I recently bought my first "real" camera, a Sony Alpha 6100 (Sony ILCE-6100).
I select that both, `.jpg` and `.arw` should be stored. 
When I compare the `.jpg` and the `.arw` picture the geometry looks a bit different. 
Lines that are straight in the `.jpg` file look slightly curved in the `.arw` file. 
Therefore, I tried to process some of the raw images using [RawTherapee 5.8](http://www.rawtherapee.com/) to fix this but failed.

When I click at the `Transform` tool and go to `Lens / Geometry` I tried to fix it by using the `Profiled Lens Correction`. By default, `Automatic (Lensfun)` is selected which does not really help. 
I tried to change it to `Manually` but I cannot find the Sony ILCE-6100 camera, nor the 3.5-5.6/16-50 OSS kit lens I'm using. There is also the option to import some LCP file but I could not find any and I have no idea what it is and where I can find it.

What is the best way to fix the geometry using RawTherapee?

(I hope I got the English terminology right, I'm using RawTherapee with a different language and therefore do not know how it is called exactly in English. Let me know if you have trouble following my descriptions.)

**EDIT:**

I realized that the problem can be fixed by using the `Distortion Correction` instead of the `Profiled Lens Correction`. However, I keep the thread open for now since somebody might be able to help me with the missing entries in the `Lensfun` database.

Comment: Related: [Why does AWR (Sony Raw) file curve at the edge when editing in Photoshop?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/73306/15871) and [Why does lens distortion correction in Capture One also crop?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/69808/15871) and [Canon DSLR Lens Correction](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/35308/15871)

Answer (score 2):

The "Sony E 16-50mm f/3.5-5.6 OSS PZ" lens is listed in lensfun's database as supported starting with version 1.534, but it does not yet appear that there's an entry for the Alpha 6100. If you visit the web site, you can find instructions for generating images to submit for them to analyze to get new cameras and/or lenses supported. The documentation also describes how to just update the lens/camera database if you can't fully upgrade the software.

Comment: Can you provide some information on where and how to download the new dB? I looked at https://github.com/lensfun/lensfun/blob/master/data/db/slr-sony.xml and replaced the `slr-sony.xml` file in my `RawTherapee/5.8/share/lensfun/version_1/slr-sony.xml` and `RawTherapee/5.8/share/lensfun/slr-sony.xml` but it did not work.
It also seems like if the lens is not listed in this `.xml` file.

Comment: @user7431005 See [here](http://lensfun.sourceforge.net/manual/v0.3.2/lensfun-update-data.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the a6100 precooks raw files in some new way, the important corrections* should be exactly the same as for an a6000 (ILCE-6000) with the same lens attached.

Vital corrections for the SELP1650 are all about distortion: Without correction, that lens at 16mm looks like a fisheye run over by a truck, that is why you can't turn it off in camera. CA/vignetting correction should be reasonably similar between two 24MP sensors designed for DSLMs (I would be cautious about mixing vignetting corrections between NEX-7 and a6000/a6100, these sensors differ a lot in their pixel shading behaviour since the former was a design originally for a DSLR).