# Was there a Canon lens correction tool that output the lens corrected raw files for a folder of pictures?

Tags: canon, software, lens-correction

The canon raw photo file was not lens corrected, such as the discussion in this post.([Canon DSLR Lens Correction](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35308/canon-dslr-lens-correction))
However, some photo editing software could not apply the lens correction itself.

Was there a Canon lens correction tool that output the lens corrected raw files for a folder of pictures? i.e. does lens correction for a folder of the raw files and allow other software to edit the lens corrected raw files?

Comment: AFAIK lens correction (distortion, vignetiing and CA) is always done **after** demosaicing (or as part of it).

Comment: If your software do not do lens correction probably will be better to change the software.